# Why is my .bat file doing a infinit loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rsync

I've created a `.bat` file for running my cwRsync script.

From CMD line, this works great:

> rsync -avz ./ *{destination}* --chmod=ugo=rwX --rsh "ssh -i id_rsync -p 9672" --recursive --delete

Now, If I put this in a `.bat` file, it just goes into a infinit loop. Thisi s my bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO ** Pushing files **

SET CWLOCAL = "C:/dev/view-resources"
SET CWREMOTE = "user@mydevserver.com:/home/dev"
SET EXLUDES = "--exclude=.git* --exclude=*.scss --exclude=cache"

rsync -avz %CWLOCAL% %CWREMOTE% --chmod=ugo=rwX --rsh "ssh -i id_rds -p 9672" --recursive %EXCLUDES% --delete
```

Why is this .bat file looping? I've tried adding `end` at the end, but that is not helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you named your bat file `rsync.bat`

The command `rsync -avz` invokes rsync.bat not rsync.exe